# What to do when a promise cannot be passed down to a thirdparty library?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am using the node.js libraries nomnom for command line parsing and [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md)'s promises.

Nomnom offers to execute [commands](https://github.com/harthur/nomnom) via a callback. Unfortunately, the callback doesn't support returning promises.

I was wondering, what is the best way to handle this interface mismatch?
I was thinking adding a busy loop that blocks until a promise is resolved / rejected  (using isPending ) in this case.
Is there a better way ?

```
var parser = require("nomnom");
parser.command('somecommand').callback(function(opts) {
  var p = thisFuncReturnsAPromise();
  //have to block here since
  //nomnom expects at the end of the callback that processing of the command is done.
})
```

Comment: just write an anon then method and call the callback with the argument from  inside. don't block.

Comment: You'd promisify it. It's a good question - let me find the duplicate real quick.

Comment: Not sure how to promisify it. Added sample code to make the case a bit more clear.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate in this case, since nomnom needs the callback.

Comment: @JE42: If you say that the `callback()` method expects a synchronous callback, but you want to do something asynchronous and wait for it, then this is impossible. It doesn't have to do with promises (`thisFuncReturnsAPromise()` could as well be `thisFuncTakesACallback()`), but you just cannot use `nomnom`. File a bug that you need async support, or fork the lib on your own.

Comment: Ok. so there is no node.js api that forces the processing of async code in the middle of synchronous code ?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum i think it would be great if you could remove the duplicate flag, as this is clearly not the same.

Comment: I think it still is - it's the same core problem (working with promises in a callback API) but as you wish. I have reopened the question.

Comment: I think that @Bergi has had the key insight here. In order to better understand the word "impossible",  I took a deeper dive into bluebirds code and Node.js async processing APIs. It does not allow any function scheduled via process.nextTick to be executed during another function. Since bluebird executes the resolve via process.nextTick, there is no way to wait for this to happen without changing the 3rd party library. the only way would be if node.js had offered an API like "process.executeEveryThingThatWasScheduledForNextTickNow()".

Answer (score 0):

```
var promise = new Bluebird(function(resolve, reject) { //Create a promise
    myLib.doStuff(function() {
        resolve(); //In a callback you resolve the promise
    });
}); 

promise.then(function() { //Use the promise
    console.log('Stuff done');
});
```

Comment: That's not really how you'd do it in BB.

Comment: Changed it for the BB behaviour, is it right this way?
But the point is, resolve the promise inside the callback.

Comment: No, bluebird would jsut do `Promise.promisifyAll` on a whole module and convert it to a complaint API in a single command assuming it uses correct node conventions for callbacks. See the question I closed as a dupe.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum please check out the sample code. I don't think this is a dupe.

Comment: @JE42 please check the "2. Plain callback:" option in the dupe - it describes the exact same scenario.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Case 2 describes the case where I have control of the code that requires the result of the callback. Here the roles are flipped. I provide the callback and nomnom can execute code after the callback completes.